# DATEDIFF function on SQL server returns a null value when I use variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I am trying to get the total of minutes between a start time and end time. This data is found on the same table, same column and I have set a variable to return the values I need.

So far, that is working fine. Now, the problem comes when I use DATEDIFF with the variables as it returns `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @hol datetime

SET @hol = (
    SELECT fecha_Registro  
    FROM Registro  
    WHERE id_Registro = 4  
        AND id_Tipo_Registro = 2
);  

SELECT @hol as varText 

DECLARE @bye DATETIME 

SET @hol = (
    SELECT fecha_Registro  
    FROM Registro  
    WHERE id_Registro = 3  
        AND id_Tipo_Registro = 1
);  

SELECT @hol as varText2  

SELECT DATEDIFF(MI, @bye, @hol) as total_minutos
```

As you can see the variables have the correct values on them, so, I am not understanding why does it comes back null. When I do it with the actual dates, it works fine.

Comment: Show us your code attempt.

Comment: Don't worry about the image, most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: Don't attach an image with your code. Instead, [edit] your question to include your code as formatted text.

Comment: Images can't be copied, tested and executed. Post the code in the question itself. Otherwise people will have to retype whatever is in the image just to reproduce the problem. Most won't even bother

Comment: As we can see??? Without sample data we can't see anything.

Comment: Never mind, I found the error :)

Comment: @AndreaCastle So, if it was what Michal said, please accept that answer, or if it was something else, please post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `@bye` variable, which isn't assigned anywhere. So it gets `NULL` default value, so `DATEDIFF(MI, @bye, @hol)` evalutes to `null` as well.

One more possibility is that query

```
select fecha_Registro  
from Registro  
where id_Registro = 3  
and id_Tipo_Registro = 1
```

returns `NULL`.

Comment: you are right Michal thank you so much! I noticed and that was a basic veeeeery basic error on my part. Guess 4am is not the best time to be doing this.